# Working with time in the iPhone

Tags: iphone, arrays, date, time, function

I have two arrays with time values in them in this format.  00:00:00 which is minutes:seconds:miliseconds.  Can someone show me any easy way of adding an subtracting these values?  I know I can if I break them down but I am looking for a way to do it without of code.  I can get the last values which is what I want to work with like this [myArray lastObject]  I tried [[myArray1 lastObject] date] - [[myArray2 lastObject] date], buy as you know that did not work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have 3 values for each time, something like:

```
struct TimePoint {
  int minutes;
  int seconds;
  int milliseconds;
};
```

If that's right, here is some code to calculate the difference:

```
// input is struct TimePoint t1, t2.
NSTimeInterval time1 = 60 * t1.minutes + t1.seconds + 0.001 * t1.milliseconds;
NSTimeInterval time2 = 60 * t2.minutes + t2.seconds + 0.001 * t2.milliseconds;
NSTimeInterval timeDifference = time1 - time2;
```

It sounds like you've also been considering working with `NSDate` objects.  If you want to do that - suppose you want to see how much time has passed from `NSDate* date1` to `NSDate* date2` -- then you could use the following method ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate:)):

```
NSTimeInterval timeDiff = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
// value is a double in seconds; might be negative if date2 was first
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `NSDate`, `NDateComponents`, and `NSCalendar`.  Study the [Date and Time Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html), which has a whole section on doing calendar-based calculations like adding hours or subtracting days.